# CMS Payroll-Based Journal

Tags: soda

I work for the state of Washington dept of Social & Health Services as development lead for the nursing home rates section. I need to download the Payroll-Based Journal from data.cms.gov to a sql table. I am already doing this for the Star and QM tables. I do this through a nightly job to check to see if newer data is available on the cloud and update my tables if it is available.

I have found the urls for individual views for a specific quarter for PBJ but I haven't found the entire dataset -- is that available (like it is for STAR and QM)?

My current method downloads the jSON for the views but it only has Q1 and Q2 for PBJ. When I use the browse there is Q1, Q2 and Q3 -- why the difference? Can I download the jSON source for the browse results instead of the views?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dataset you're using where you only see two quarters?

Comment: https://data.cms.gov/api/views

Comment: at this url I am able to download the jSON into a datatable and analyze whether or not I will use the link -- using the id and name elements

Answer (score 0):

PBJ data is submitted and published on a quarterly basis.  So far, CMS has published 3 quarters worth of data.  For more information, you can view the Public Use File documentation here: https://data.cms.gov/Special-Programs-Initiatives-Long-Term-Care-Facili/PBJ-PUF-Documentation-2018-01-23/ygny-gzks.

The three quarters they have published include the calendar based quarter time period rather than the expected fiscal based time period.  I have contacted CMS to have this issue corrected.

Here are the three quarters they have published:

---

**Dataset Label:**  PBJ Daily Nurse Staffing 2017 Q1

**Actual Quarter:** 2017 Q2

**Expected Date Range:**    10/1/2016-12/31/2016

**Included Date Range:**    1/1/2017-3/31/2017

**Link:**   https://data.cms.gov/Special-Programs-Initiatives-Long-Term-Care-Facili/PBJ-Daily-Nurse-Staffing-2017-Q1/afnb-m6tn

**JSON API:**   https://data.cms.gov/resource/pre7-wbdk.json

---

**Dataset Label:**  PBJ Daily Nurse Staffing 2017 Q2

**Actual Quarter:** 2017 Q3

**Expected Date Range:**    1/1/2017-3/31/2017

**Included Date Range:**    4/1/2017-6/30/2017

**Link:**   https://data.cms.gov/Special-Programs-Initiatives-Long-Term-Care-Facili/PBJ-Daily-Nurse-Staffing-2017-Q2/utrm-5phx

**JSON API:**   https://data.cms.gov/resource/9h2r-8ja3.json

---

**Dataset Label:**  PBJ Daily Nurse Staffing 2017 Q3

**Actual Quarter:** 2017 Q4

**Expected Date Range:**    4/1/2017-6/30/2017

**Included Date Range:**    7/1/2017-9/30-2017

**Link:**   https://data.cms.gov/Special-Programs-Initiatives-Long-Term-Care-Facili/PBJ-Daily-Nurse-Staffing-2017-Q3/bpnu-uej3

**JSON API:**   https://data.cms.gov/resource/krv7-6tjb.json

---

I work for ezPBJ, a company that specializes in assisting facilities with PBJ preparation, validation, and submission.  We will soon be releasing a free tool that will allow users to compare their PBJ data with that of any other facility in the US.  If you'd like to be included our our list of beta testers, send me an email at jaime@ezpbj.com.

Thanks,

Jaime

CIO, ezPBJ

Comment: Thank you Jamie -- This isn't quite what I am looking for. I am trying to find either one source for all PBJ file or a source for the list of quarterly files with ther urls. I am creating a nightly job that will automatically download any new PBJ data to a sql table for our Rates Analysts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out a solution ....

http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?q=pbj

will give me a json stream that I can put into a dataset and get all the url's I am looking for.